# ASP.NET MVC EditorFor custom javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2

The following statement:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Material.Serial) %>
```

Generates the following code;

```
<div class="editor-field">  
    <input type="text" value="" name="Material.Serial" id="Material_Serial" class="input-validation-error">  
    <span id="Material_Serial_validationMessage" class="field-validation-error">Debe ingresar un serial</span>  
</div>
```

I want to add an `onkeypress` javascript attribute to my input through the `EditorFor` statement, I have tried to do the following:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Material.Serial, new{ onkeypress = "return disableEnterKey(event)"})%>
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

Its difficult to pass Additional attributes to EditorFor templates, but alternatively the same functionality could be implemented using jQuery or something similar:

```
$('#Material_Serial').keypress(function(event) {

  disableEnterKey(event);

});
```

Comment: Ok, but how do you make sure this bit of code is always inserted in the view when there's a Material.Serial field in the model?

Answer (score 5):

Use the following .... note the last part in the code.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onchange="alert('Hello World')" } })
```

HTML generated for the above will be

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Title must be a string with a maximum length of 255." data-val-length-max="255" data-val-required="The Title field is required." id="Title" name="Title" onchange="alert(&#39;Hello World&#39;)" type="text" value="" />
```